# OpenLayers skip loading of vector features above a specific resolution

Tags: openlayers

I am using OpenLayers to read vector features from GeoServer with a custom loader function on the source.
Since there are a lot of features, I would like to skip loading them above a specific resolution, for example 20.
The loader function receives the resolution as a parameter, so I can simply return without any xhr loading. It seems fine until this point.
The problem is that OpenLayers keeps a record of all extents loaded (loadedExtentsRtree_), and inserts this skipped extent. So next time the user zooms below the threshold, it does not load anything, because it remembers that this extent was already loaded - in fact it was not.
There is a removeLoadedExtent method - but at the time of skipping this extent is not there yet.
I checked the source code, and OpenLayers calls my loader first, and then inserts the extent.

Does anyone have any idea? I am struggling with this for a while now. Thank you!

Comment: I think the extent is set when the loader is called.  In the example loader https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector.html#~Options how would calling `removeLoadedExtent` when the xhr fails be any different to calling it if you don't send the xhr?  However you can also call `removeLoadedExtent` in a custom strategy function as in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/layer/Graticule.js#L509

Comment: @Mike, thank you for your answer. In [Vector.js](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source/Vector.js) there is the loadFeature function, and around line 918 the loader is called. After this, line 938, the extent is inserted into the **loadedExtentsRtree**, even if I decide not to load it. As far as I understand, removing loaded extent when the xhr fails in the example you cited works because it takes some time for the xhr to fail, and at that time line 938 will already be executed.

Comment: @Mike, the custom strategy was a good hint, thanks. I simply have to return an empty array if above the desired resolution, and everything works. Thank you! Sorry, I am new here, how can I mark your comment as the one that helped me to solve the problem?